# Java Method to return string reversed / string eating file

Tags: java, recursion, java.util.scanner, reverse

I'm trying to write a recursive method that will read a bunch of lines in from a file and output it reversed. First of all, I made the method:

```
public static String reverseMe(String s)
{
    if(s.length() == 0)
    {
        return "";
    }
    else 
    {
        return s.charAt(s.length()-1) + reverseMe(s.substring(0, s.length()-1));//Recursive method to reverse order of numbers in the string
    }
}
```

Hopefully this should work to reverse the string. I'm not sure if it works though, because my scanner has been messing up (again).
My main is like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
   Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("prog512h.dat"));
   String fileRead = "";
   while (fileIn.hasNext())
   {
       fileIn.reset();
       fileRead += fileIn.next();
    }
   reverseMe(fileRead);
   }
  }
```

I keep having this issue when reading in from a file, using the method .hasNext() eats up all of the data within the file and so when I try to add the text within the file using .next(), I get an error that says I don't have it. However, when I run this program, nothing happens, prints, or returns. I don't know where it's messing up. Help?

Comment: Why are you calling `Scanner.reset()` in your loop?

Comment: Did you use the debugger to see what is happening? What error message are you getting?

Comment: Are you certain the `File` is where Java expects it to be?

Comment: You don't really need recursion for this. A simple for loop would do the job adequately and far more intuitively. And I agree with the others, the reset of the Scanner in your while loop looks like a potential culprit for your issue.

Comment: I was hoping Scanner.reset() would allow me to go through the file again. The debugger isn't returning anything which is really odd. And yes, i'm pretty sure that the file is correct. Also, I need to do it in recursion because it's for an assignment.

Comment: Taking out the .reset() method didn't change anything, but the method works just fine.